# How to print case-sensitive array

Tags: ruby

I have an array that includes strings with a mix of different cases like follows:

```
WEBSITES = ["The Atlantic", "BBC", "CNN", "The Economist" ]
```

When I loop through this array (specifically a select helper in my Rails form), I get

```
"The atlantic", "Bbc", "Cnn", "The economist"
```

How do I print it with the same format as in the array?

**EDIT:**

Here are my files (Rails).

The array is in my model

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  WEBSITES = ["The Atlantic", "BBC", "CNN", "The Economist"]
end
```

The form is here

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <% Survey::WEBSITES.each_with_index do |site, index| %>
    <%= f.label site %>
    <%= f.select "answer_field_#{ index +1 }".to_sym %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you post your helper and how you print it?

Comment: Thanks @Zippie, I just added my files. I don't explicitly call a `capitalize` method. Is there something I can do to prevent that from happening?

Comment: i have no clue why this is happening..sorry :/

Comment: can you try this: 
`<%= f.label site, "#{site}" %>`

Comment: That works! Thanks. Can you add that to your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.label site, "#{site}" %>
```